# How to store global preferences at project level

Tags: eclipse-pde

I am doing POC on how global level preferences can be store at Project level as well.

I have created the sample application in which I have created the `MyPreferencePage` page and used the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension to add this page in eclipse preferences.

I am also able to save the page data and retrieve it using the code `setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore())`.
 Now I want to create new page under projects properties level and should able to store page values at project level.

Below is the code for `MyPreferencePage` and `preferencePages` extension.

```xml
<extension
 point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
 <page
 class="com.vogella.preference.MyPreferencePage"
 id="com.vogella.preference.page1"
 name="MyPreferencePage">
 </page>
 </extension>
```

```java
public class MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements
 IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

 public MyPreferencePage() {
 super(GRID);

 }

 @Override
 public void createFieldEditors() {
 addField(new DirectoryFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH,
 "&Directory preference:", getFieldEditorParent()));

 addField(new BooleanFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_BOOLEAN,
 "&An example of a boolean preference", getFieldEditorParent()));

 addField(new RadioGroupFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_CHOICE,
 "An example of a multiple-choice preference", 1,
 new String[][] { { "&Choice 1", "choice1" },
 { "C&hoice 2", "choice2" } }, getFieldEditorParent()));

 addField(new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_STRING,
 "A &text preference:", getFieldEditorParent()));

 addField(new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_STRING,
 "A &text preference:", getFieldEditorParent()));

 }

 @Override
 public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
 setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
 setDescription("A demonstration of a preference page implementation");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ScopedPreferenceStore` for the project as the preference store passed to `setPreferenceStore`. Create it like this:

```java
new ScopedPreferenceStore(new ProjectScope(project), "your plugin id");
```

where `project` is the `IProject` for the project.